# MS Access: Keeping grouped report controls on the same page

Tags: ms-access, report

I have been begrudgingly using Access reports and figured out most of the quirky caveats to the system, but there is one issue I am facing to which I am unsure if there is a remedy.

Basically, I have a report where the question title is displayed above its relevant chart and I would like for the title and chart to remain on the same page, so that when other controls grow the two are forced onto the next page together (otherwise I would just insert a page break). I thought grouping these controls would have the desired effect but alas no luck.

I have attached pictures of the group i wish to keep together in design view, and the print preview of my dreams being shattered when they are not. (These are attached as links below since I am not allowed to embed....)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Grouped controls in design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3B1K.png)

[Failure in print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gFn8.png)

Comment: *begrudgingly using Access reports and figured out most of the quirky caveats* -- yes, this is the most promising approach to get help of users of said product. Not.

Comment: and there i was thinking fellow Access report builders might share my distaste with some of Microsoft's questionable design choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building all graphs on report, use sub-reports to group items together. Simply, create new report with title/graph, and insert it into your main report. I suggest you do the same with other graphs, and if possible reuse sub-reports.
This way is much easier to maintain reports and you can use 'keep together' function.

Here is example of one of my reports that I automatically export in PDF for each of selected vendors:

[image]

On print, I keep 4 graphs per page and here is how it looks:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Velid, I ended up using sub-reports as you suggested since it seemed like the only solution; but even these can be highly fallible too. Especially when using the can grow option, often my charts will end up spliced across pages. I have settled on using a mix of sub-reports and page breaks to create close enough to my desired effect, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. Make sure you use 'keep together' property of sub-report on main report. This will make sure it does not get split on multiple pages.